# Cannot decode QRCode text

Tags: excel, qr-code, xlwings, decoder

I am using pyzbar to decode a QR Code and save the data into Excel using Xlwings, however the decode fails

```
import xlwings as xw
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from datetime import datetime
import xlwings as xw
import glob
import time

def main():
     png_files = '1.png'
        
     wb = xw.Book('2.xlsm')  # this will open a new workbook
     sht = wb.sheets[0]
     a_column = wb.sheets[0].range('A:C')# 選取 A 欄
     a_column.clear_contents()# 清空 A 欄的內容
     
     data_list=[]
     filelist=[]
     timelist=[]

     sht.range('A1').value ='圖片名稱'
     sht.range('B1').value ='掃描時間'
     sht.range('C1').value ='條碼內容'

     img=cv2.imread(png_files)
     qrcode=decode(img)
     qr_text=qrcode.data.decode('utf-8')
     data_list.append(qr_text)
     filelist.append(png_files)
     timelist.append(str(datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')))

     c = list(zip(filelist,timelist, data_list))
     fr='A2:C'+str((len(c)+2))
     sht.range(fr).value =c
```

remove for next , just use simple code , still can not decode

```
qrcode=decode(img) # stop here
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited the question since this issue is really about the decoding of a QRCode.
I'm guessing you get a list attribute error when running the line

```
qr_text=qrcode.data.decode('utf-8')
```

However since you haven't specified what the error actually is I didn't include this in the edit in case it's not correct.
**You should update the question and clarify the error, text and location in your code.**

**Fixing the issue**
When you execute the line

```
qrcode=decode(img)
```

qrcode will be a list with 1 or more elements so qrcode has no attribute 'data'. You must select the element first then you can access data. Therefore for the first element you should change the line from

```
qr_text=qrcode.data.decode('utf-8')
```

to

```
qr_text = qrcode[0].data.decode('utf-8')
```

Or you can loop through the elements using a for loop

```
for item in qrcode:
    print(item.data.decode("utf-8"))
```